# Jconsole and JPS don't show any processes. How can I monitor my process?

Tags: java, windows, process, monitoring, jconsole

I'm trying to monitor a running process in a JVM using Jconsole (JDK1.8.0_31). However, I can't see any processes in the start window of Jconsole since the window is broken. The list for local process seems to have no height parameter set. At least that's what it looks like:

[image]

I checked for similar problems on the web. I found cases where strange permission settings for `%TMP%` caused problems for Jconsole. I checked, and I have all permissions I need (read/write and some more).

Alright, since I don't give up easily, I also found out that Jconsole takes the PID of the Java process as an argument. While trying to find the PID I noticed that JPS doesn't show any processes or JVMs even though they are clearly running (I have more than one JDK installed. Even though that shouldn't matter, I also checked if I was using the JPS from the same `$JVM\bin` folder).

[image]

So, here's my question:

**What else could cause this issue?** What else could I check?

I'd really appreciate the help because otherwise I won't be able to check which of my apps is causing this weird memory overflow on my system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I misunderstood other solutions concerning `%TMP%` permissions. I checked the permissions for `TMP` itself but the culprit was `hsperfdata_$USER` (with $USER being your username). What was wrong was that user starting the jvm needs read and write permissions for the `hsperfdata` directory. In my case the user wasn't set in the first place.

I did *right click `hsperfdata_$USER`>properties>security>edit>add>advanced* and in the field *starts with* I put in my user name and confirmed. Back at the security tab I set all permissions for my user and that's it.