# IntelliJ IDEA not Showing anything endpoints tab: "Failed to retrieve application JMX service URL"

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I have a spring boot web service that I want to see the endpoints of.  However when I run it in IntelliJ there are no endpoints displayed.  In the endpoints window I see the error

```
Failed to check application ready state: AttachProvider for the vm is not found.
Press Refresh button to reinit ready state checking
```

I am able to run the application just fine and hit the web services fine with SoapUI, but I would like to use the functionality in IntelliJ. When I click the endpoint tab or the refresh button in the endpoint tab, in the event log I get a log entry on application start that says

```
PersonMicroserviceApplication: Failed to retrieve application JMX service URL
```

I have "Enable JMX agent" checked in the run configuration.  This is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.example.microservice</groupId>
    <artifactId>person-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

NOTE: Jackson is marked as a quarantined dependency at my company's maven repository due to a security concern (I'm not sure what the security concern is), so I am using gson as my json mapper, I have the following line in my application.properties to tell spring to use gson

```
spring.http.converters.preferred-json-mapper=gson
```

The only other thing I have in my application.properties is a connect string to mongodb.  There is nothing else, so there may be something I'm missing there but in the spring documentation I saw it just said include spring-boot-starter-actuator and check enable JMX agent.

Is there anything I'm missing configuration-wise to enable this? I am on windows 10 64 bit, I am using oracles JDK 8.

Comment: Please check if it works with https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/ .

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I also encountered this problem and finally found the answer:

Starting from 2018.3.4 IntelliJ IDEA use local JMX connector for retrieving Spring Boot actuator endpoint's data.
Local JMX monitoring has some restrictions, in particular, it isn't possible to get local JMX connector address if Spring Boot application and IntelliJ IDEA JVMs have different bitness.
If it is not possible to run application on JVM with the same bitness, then, in order to fix the problem, one could add the following to Spring Boot run configuration's VM options:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port={some_port} -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

After setting:

[image]

jetbrains issue link:https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-204797

Comment: Relevant bit: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-spring-boot.html#deb79cc6 (Configuration tab / Enable JMX agent)

Comment: Does {some_port} needs to be a specific port that is related to the application? Or just some random port? Because when I’m using a random port it still doesn’t work for me.

Comment: @NoyGafni I used port 8082 (server running on port 8081) and it worked.

Answer (score 9):

set this in you VM options:

`-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost`

that what worked for me.

I found the answer here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-210665#focus=Comments-27-3544328.0-0

Comment: This worked for me too. I am using JDK17 and IntelliJ 2022.2 Ultimate edition

Comment: I've searched this answer for second time :)

Comment: This worked for me!  I needed this while on VPN because IntelliJ tries to connect to local ip instead of my VPN ip.

Answer (score 1):

You can add to application.properties this:

management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*

- after that your app will work correctly. Also I recommend you to read this article for the best understanding customizing of endpoints and actuator:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/actuator.html#actuator

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions of the `%TMP%/hsperfdata_<username>` directory ,if  does not have read and write permissions，right click hsperfdata_>properties>security>edit>add>advanced add  and confirmed;
or delete %TMP%/hsperfdata_ and restart app

> https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-210665#focus=Comments-27-4410513.0-0
> [Jconsole and JPS don't show any processes. How can I monitor my process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29163280/jconsole-and-jps-dont-show-any-processes-how-can-i-monitor-my-process)

Answer (score -1):

I am using Java 1.8 and I faced the same issue, for me it got resolved by unchecking the Enable JMX Agent in Run/Debug Configuration.
Refer the image.

[Attached Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKIl3.png)

Comment: Disabling the feature is not a resolution for the feature not working.

Answer (score -2):

I am using IntelliJ Idea 2020.1 on Windows 10 and I faced the similar problem. For me, un-checking the 'Enable JMX Agent' solves this issue. Also, I have both JDK 11 and JDK 8 on my system and I have different Java Application (microservices) run on different JDK versions but this one required JDK 1.8 (as it is not migrated yet).
See the attached snapshot:[image: Run/Debug Configuration Snapshot]

Comment: Disabling the feature is not a resolution for the feature not working.

Comment: it just disaple error.It is not solution